# Supressing warning in building Opencv with Cmake

Tags: opencv, cmake

I have a warning in building Opencv using Cmake. It suggests "Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.". But I don't know how to suppress it.

The warnings come out when I do "generate" in ccmake GUI.
The warnings are

```
 CMake Warning (dev) at apps/haartraining/CMakeLists.txt:34 (add_library):
   Policy CMP0038 is not set: Targets may not link directly to themselves.
   Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0038" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
   command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

   Target "opencv_haartraining_engine" links to itself.
 This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.


 CMake Warning (dev) at apps/haartraining/CMakeLists.txt:34 (add_library):
   Policy CMP0038 is not set: Targets may not link directly to themselves.
   Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0038" for policy details.  Use the cmake_policy
   command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

   Target "opencv_haartraining_engine" links to itself.
 This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.



Messages during last pass                                                       
                                                             CMake Version 3.2.2
Press [e] to exit help
```

How to remove this warnings? This is just warning, but can't proceed this step when I press 'e', ccmake GUI stops. So ccmake doesn't generate anything and stops.
Thanks

Comment: Which version of OpenCV? Which compiler/toolchain? From which platform are you building? Why do you ask 2 times the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37316689/cmake-policy-setting-in-building-opencv)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cmake policy setting in building Opencv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37316689/cmake-policy-setting-in-building-opencv)

Answer (score 1):

Just run ccmake with the flag given in the message:

```
ccmake -Wno-dev [source path] [build path]
```