# Cmake policy setting in building Opencv

Tags: opencv, cmake

I am not sure where to set cmake_policy. 
This [link](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/command/cmake_policy.html#command:cmake_policy) has explained cmake_policy. But not sure where to set cmake policy.
I use cmake to build Opencv and I have a lot of warnings like

```
CMake Warning (dev) at cuda_compile_generated_row_filter.2.cu.o.cmake:137 (if):
  Policy CMP0054 is not set: Only interpret if() arguments as variables or
  keywords when unquoted.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0054" for policy
  details.  Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this
  warning.
```

I need to set like  `cmake_policy(SET CMP0054 NEW)`.
Where to set this policy?
I did like

```
ppp@ppp-Inspiron-7537:~/Softwares/opencv-2.4.9/build$ cmake_policy(SET CMP0054 NEW)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `SET'
```

but I got error.
How can I set the policy?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `-Wno-dev` option for `cmake` for suppress warnings intended for developers:

```
cmake -Wno-dev <other-options> <source-dir>
```

Alternatively, if you want to set policy for the project, you need to modify its `CMakeLists.txt` file and add line

```
cmake_policy(SET CMP0054 OLD)
```

somewhere at the beginning.

Note, that you need to use **OLD** value for the property, as the project most likely relies on such variable's dereference. Setting *NEW* value will probably break project's functionality.

When project's code will be fixed, warnings won't be generated even without explicit policy set.